# How to redirect properly after logging in in an SPA

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, vue.js, single-page-application

I have a situation. I am trying to create an application that will have only one route file, `api.php` for both the web app (spa) and mobile app.The problem is now that the entire application is stateless (as it should be), I can't even login. Because, routes in `api.php` expect a token in the request header, which I don't know how to provide.I am using vue in the front-end I have this simple strategy:`<button @click="login">Login</button>`and the login method looks like this:

```
login(){
  axios.post('login',this.credentials)
       .then( window.location = "http://localhost:3000/app" );
}
```

And my route definition:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('app', function () {
        return view('index');
    });
});
```

But it redirects me back to the login page. I wish I could do something like `window.header = Bearer myLongToken`. I am using JWT, if that helps.

---

**Update:**

It looks like there is something else going on. If I remove the `role:admin` middleware, then I get redirected to desired route, but if I add the middleware, I get redirected back to the login route even if the credentials are valid.

```
// Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
     Route::get('app', function () {
         return view('index');
     });
// });
```

Comment: can you display the error?

Comment: @FarisDewantoro Question updated